# What is the difference between a .wl package and a .m package?

Tags: packages, files-and-directories

In *Mathematica* 10.x, one now has both `.wl` *Wolfram Language* Packages and `.m` *Wolfram Mathematica* Packages.

- What's the difference?
- Is one of the two formats to be preferred in certain situations and, if so, which one and where?
- Why, after making the menu selection `File > New > Package`, entering code, and saving, is it offered as default to save in the `.wl` format?

I have read the discussion [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/297046?p_p_auth=bhuy8Kl4), but failed to see there satisfactory answers to those questions.

*Note:* I don't find any listing of *Wolfram Language* Package [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: 1. just the file ending AFAIK, 2. if you have installed matlab (or another software which also uses .m file extension) it is easier to let the OS distinguish between matlab files and mathematica packages, 3. because that now seems to be the extension prefered by WRI, most probably more for marketing reasons than because of 2. My impression is that .m was just left to work for compatibility reasons, but maybe I'm wrong with that...

Comment: it seems that there are differences in the order in which package files are loaded (check the wolfram groups discussion mentioned in your question). But that will probably only be relevant when you mix old (.m+Kernel/init.m) and new (.wl only) conventions...

Comment: one more thing: it seems that workbench still doesn't know about .wl files, but maybe I just don't know how to get the most recent version, does anyone know what the newest is? The update site announces 2.0.138 to be the newest for years...

Comment: Also, .m files are Objective C source files on the Mac, I believe.

Comment: avoiding collision with matlab is a very good / welcome reason!

Comment: Currently all descriptions involving packages in Wolfram Language Documentation use files ending with `.m` instead of `.wl`, which is quite weird.

Comment: @Albert Would you consider converting your comments into an answer? You have made some interesting observations and the question has generated quite a bit of interest in the months since it has been asked, so it would be worthy of an answer.

Comment: @MarcoB: good point, I was not expecting noone else would give a better answer. I just have added one.

Answer (score 20):

As after half a year there is still no answer, here are some very short answers from my comments:

1. the difference is just the file ending as far as I know.
2. if you have installed MATLAB (or another software which also uses .m file extension) it is easier to let the OS distinguish between MATLAB files and *Mathematica* packages.
3. because that now seems to be the extension preferred by WRI, most probably more for marketing reasons than because of answer 2. My impression is that .m was just left to work for compatibility reasons, but maybe I'm wrong with that...

Despite answer 1. there is obviously a new problem when *Mathematica* needs to load a package and there are both a .m and a .wl file with the same name. It seems that there are differences in the order in which package files are loaded and that has seen some changes at least in early 10.x versions (check the Wolfram Groups discussion mentioned in your question). But that will probably only be relevant when you mix old (.m) and new (.wl) conventions which is something you obviously should avoid.

One more difference is the support within the Workbench which still doesn't know about .wl files. But maybe I just don't know how to get the most recent version, does anyone know what the newest is? The update site announces 2.0.138 to be the newest for years (still true in June 2016)...

Comment: I am agree with your second viewpoint, so I didn't install the MATLAB on my laptop. In addtion, the recent **Workbench** version I think is V3.0, because I achieved a copy from my friend. Please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k0CYO.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG: I know that V3.0 of Workbench exists and is used by WRI internally since many years. The problem is that it still seems to not be officially released according to [official product site](https://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: I have installed the **V3.0** (64bit) on my working PC, unfortunately, that PC is 32bit, so it @Albert Retey cannot be used normally. In addtion, I known that the **V2.0** cannot **debug** with the *Mathematica* 10.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG: I know that V3 exists and is used internally and usually can be received for beta testing form WRI if one asks for it. But that is the state now for years, I'd guess about 2008. My point is that there still is no **official release** of a newer version than 2.0.138...

Comment: To keep this uptodate: Please note [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127318/764).  Workbench is now being supported and continued exclusively as a plugin to Eclispe IDE: [Wolrfram Website Information](http://www.wolfram.com/workbench/). And as of today, Workbench does not seem to know about any `.wl` files. So no rebranding for the techies it seems. :)