# Wolfram Workbench Installation Issue

Tags: workbench

In attempting to reinstall Wolfram Workbench 2.0 after a unused hiatus and system reconfiguration, I downloaded both Eclipse and Workbench. Both seem to run.  However, in following the Wolfram video on installing WWB Adam Berry suggests that before getting started one should Select the Help Menu and the Install Workbench Extras.  Following the video I check the box for the single available feature Subclipse to add client support for SVN source control to the WWB.  In pressing Finish I get the error:

"Could not connect to update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x"

Consequently, I can not perform subsequent steps as given in the Workbench Installation Video. It seems that the subclipse.tigris.org pages references are now missing and the site is decommissioning. Checking this subclipse.tigris.org website indicates it will be gone by July 2020,but you had to ask before 1 June 2020. The files referred to no longer seem to exist.  For example, there is no "Team" support as suggested in the video.

How can one resolve this issue?  Is it even necessary any longer to do this?  If so, how can one now setup WWB to establish the setup features referred to in the video?  If not necessary, perhaps the Installation Video needs to updated.

I am running 12.1 on Windows 10/64.

Comment: I imagine you've seen the instructions at <https://support.wolfram.com/27221>, but I've seen the current version of Workbench that is installed into Eclipse referred to as "Wolfram Workbench 3" <https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127318/where-can-i-get-workbench-3-and-why-do-i-need-it>.  Just checking since you mentioned "Workbench 2.0".

Comment: On the phone to WR.  They no longer support the standalone Workbench (not sure 3.0 every really became a reality though its mentioned here and there.  They support a specific plug-in for Eclipse, which as yet I haven't quite gotten working.  At least, not as suggested in the WR video tutorials that are in need of revision with respect to installation issues.

Answer (score 4):

Executing `Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolfmertig/WolframWorkbenchInstall/master/WWBInstall.wl"]`
(or `Import["https://wolfr.am/NHGLnZMa"]`) will install Wolfram Workbench fully automatically.

Comment: +1. Great work!

Comment: Running MMA Ver. 13.1.0, this no longer works with latest version of Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
Build id: 20230907-1323
OS: Windows 11, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 21.0.1+12-LTS-29
Java version: 21.0.1
) and Workbench Version: 10.2.75.