# How to detect unused local variables?

Tags: notebooks, workbench, syntax-highlighting, debugging

I have some code (that I did not write) that has many unused local variables in Modules. I would like to clean this up. Is there any automated way to do this or to make it more clear that a local variable is unused (it would be great if it could be highlighted in a different color for example)?

I am using the standard notebook environment. Is it possible within that? Or should I be using something else like Workbench for this?

Comment: As of version 12.3, you can use the interactive analyzer, in the Menu bar, `Evaluation` > `Analyze Cell` or `Analyze Notebook`.

Answer (score 6):

Wolfram Workbench is nice for this, but you could also try the "CodeInspector`" package:
[image]

Comment: Nice. +1. I think it should say `a` is uninitialized, but it what the OP asked.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great! Is there an easy way to refer to a certain input cell instead of having to convert it to a string by hand? Say if `In[2]` in the above had contained `Module[{a,b,c},a+1]`. Or alternatively if we want to check if `CodeInspectSummarize[#, CodeInspect[#]] &@"Module[{a,b,c},a+1]"` contains any unreferenced variables by applying the CodeInspector to the (unevaluated) `In[3]`. (In the latter case I would expect the answer to be no since the `Module` is within a string.)

Comment: @Kvothe you could save your notebook as a package or use NotebookRead, but I would really use Workbench. I once wrote a installation script, not sure if it still works on all operating systems: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225038/29

Comment: This is in product v12.3

Comment: @RolfMertig, would you mind adding an answer using the Workbench in that case. I already installed it (Eclipse + Plugin) following https://support.wolfram.com/27221. I simply dragged and dropped a .m file into it where I would like to find the unreferenced local variables. I don't know what to do next. (Edit: Sorry I think I figured it out.)

Comment: So I found that by putting the .m in an open mathematica project I could find the unused variables at the "Problems" tab. I also found I could cycle through them using `Ctrl + .`. Is there an even more efficient way to let the Workbench remove all of these at once?

Comment: @Kvothe I don't know, but you could just call Wolfram support?