# List of development tools for the Wolfram Language and Mathematica

Tags: free-wolfram-engine, development, plugins, ide

What free and commercial tools for Wolfram Language development do you know? A while back I did a review of free tools for developing in the Wolfram Language (you can read my review with the help of a translator [here](https://tproger.ru/articles/besplatnye-instrumenty-dlja-wolfram-language)). But time goes by, the number of tools and technologies grows, and my review doesn't get any more hits. So I thought I should do a similar review, but first in English, second on the most popular and useful resource on Wolfram Language, and third in a format where I can easily add new tools to my review without editing the whole page/article.

I think this would be super-useful for beginners and advanced users alike - a list of all available tools with pros and cons. I think there can be both plugins for code editors and entire IDEs. Or alternative interfaces like Jupyter.

Comment: I am still waiting for a real easy to use debugger (like the one that comes with Matlab). Been waiting for 20 years now. May be Wolfram will make one in the next 20 years? But I have given up hope.

Comment: @Nasser did you try to use debugger from Eclipse + Wolrfam Workbench?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. But that is useless really. I posted question about it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274227/is-starting-wolfram-workbench-when-mathematica-already-running-not-allowed) . Many issues with it that it is not practical to use. I can't issue Mathematica commands inside it. Can only look. And can not have another Mathematica notebook running at same time. So I use Maple now since it has a debugger. Not GUI based but only command line (like gdb (GNU debugger) on Unix) so not very easy to use, but at least I can debug with it and use it all the time

Comment: @Nasser did you try debugger in Mathematica main menu _Evaluation > Debugger_?

Comment: Yes!  This is also useless. First it only works with notebooks. Not m files. So can't use it to debug packages. It is also very hard to use. I think there are only 5 people living who actually use it and know how.  I am asking for normal, _easy_ to use debugger. Like one that comes with Matlab and Visual studio for example. All other developments tools in Mathematica mean very little to me personally, if there is no debugger as well. but this is just me. Others, much better programmers, might not need a debugger at all.

Comment: @Nasser I very rarely use both debuggers I mentioned above. Usually, when I write code in Notebook, I am forced to write short blocks with the possibility to execute each small piece of code separately. This in itself is more convenient than the debugger I am used to using in Visual Studio.

Comment: I very rarely use both debuggers Well, then you must be one of those really good programmers I was talking about who does not need one :) see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/f5n00/programming_masterminds_dont_use_debuggers_why/)  but I think the average programmers do need a debugger to help them. I myself (consider my self an average programmer) do find it useful many times to help me find my bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

*Let me know in comments if you see anything missing - I will add.*

---

### OFFICIAL

##### Some summaries:

- For WORKBENCH read: https://support.wolfram.com/27221
- [Resources for Software Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/resources/)
- [Wolfram for Software Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/developer)
- ALSO - the Wolf on GitHub: https://github.com/WolframResearch

##### Listen to this 2021 video:

- [Developing Wolfram Language Code in Other Editors and IDEs with LSP](https://youtu.be/nXVEOUMZbzQ?si=8wPYqMh6CN8JYjZN)

##### Don't miss essentials and random things like:

- [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository)
- [Wolfram Language Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository)
- ALL official repos: https://resources.wolframcloud.com
- [Tutorial for developing Paclets in Wolfram Workbench 3.0 as of V12.2+](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2565414)

### EXTERNAL

##### IntelliJ

- https://wlplugin.halirutan.de
- [Open-source IntelliJ IDEA plugin to support Mathematica development](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/13)

##### Wolfram Language Javascript Frontend

- https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend
- https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs
- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3043956

##### IDE by @b3m2a1 ​

- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1655203
- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1655716
- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1644794

##### Visual Studio Code Client for Wolfram Language Server

- https://github.com/kenkangxgwe/vscode-lsp-wl#visual-studio-code-client-for-wolfram-language-server

##### VisX: Visual Interface to the Wolfram Language

- https://visx.io
- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1124967
- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2713297

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the answer to my question I expected to see! I was especially happy that you included our project with Kirill in your list =)

Comment: I wrote to the VisX developer asking to participate in beta testing, but he replied that the testing was over. It's a pity I didn't manage to see what he managed to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

Since no one is posting, I will try to help, even though I've shared this answer under other similar questions. :)

There is an actively developing freeware tool for the Wolfram Engine called **WLJS (Wolfram Language Javascript) Frontend**.

[image: plotting functions]

[image: dynamics]

### Why create another frontend when there is Jupyter?

A new frontend was created from scratch in order to overcome the limitations of the API and cell editor. It provides some benefits:

- Partial `Boxes` support, allowing the maintenance of Mathematica's famous 2D mathematical input/output.
- 2D, 3D graphics were rebuilt from scratch using d3.js and three.js (no Export SVG is used as in most approaches)
- Native dynamics support (sliders, plots, event-based systems, but implemented in a different way).
- Editable output cells.
- Native binding to Javascript cell types (WebGL, any web framework can be used in conjunction with Wolfram Language).
- HTML, mermaid, gpt3.5, or any other cell type you prefer can be added.
- Only installed `wolframscript` is required.

If someone is interested:

- [**Releases**](https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend/releases)
- [**Docs**](https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/)

Comment: (+1) There is also [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/), of course, which gives free access to Mathematica. Also, personally I find [this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)  good :-)

Comment: True! I was a big fan of Wolfram Cloud until they changed the policy and removed all of my notebooks ;D After that my mind got infected by an open-source and cloudless technologies

Comment: @KirillVasin what do you mean by `cloudless technologies`? You mean something that does not requires access to the internet to use?

Comment: @Nasser, correct! An immortal technology that will work any time and does require only wolframscript installed ;)

Comment: Looks great! And the interface feels much much better than jupyter notebooks. How's development going?

Comment: Thanks, @jWey. :) In principle i have been using it already for a half of a year in the university with my students. Most features for 2D plotting are implemented as well as for dynamics. Now we are refactoring the code base to improve stability and UI right now. No breaking or huge changes are expected

Comment: (+1) Very nice!  I want to use it :-)