# Wolfram language vs Mathematica

Tags: packages

Suppose I am developing a package (because I am :)). *Mathematica* gives me the option of creating a Wolfram Language (.wl) package or a Mathematica (.m) package. Why would I choose one vs the other? There seem to be a couple of questions on the (seemingly nonexistent) differences between *Mathematica* and WL, but they don't quite address the above.

Comment: .wl has the great advantage of not conflicting with MATLAB's m files

Comment: @GustavoDelfino And also ObjectiveC files on the Mac (which is why I am tempted to use .wl) but I am worried that there is some weird semantic difference I am missing.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98981) might be a dupe.

Comment: @J.M. Yup, it looks very similar.

Comment: They are equivalent, it's just a rebranding PR move

Comment: I am using the [Workbench-plugin](http://www.wolfram.com/workbench/) for Eclipse for writing packages, which is the only version of Workbench left, that is being supported. In Workbench whenever I start a new package, everything is automatically named with `.m` suffix. TL;DR whatever branding move there is - it appears to not really have gotten down to tutorials, guides and tools very much, has it?

Comment: @gwr precisely why I am confused :(