# What's the difference between these formats?

Tags: files-and-directories, format

Unfortunately, the documentation does not give a substantive explanation of the differences between these formats:

1. **WDF vs WXF**
2. **WLNET vs WMLF**
3. M vs WL - was answered here: [What is the difference between a .wl package and a .m package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98981/what-is-the-difference-between-a-wl-package-and-a-m-package)

I'd like to gather some more details on these and know when to use which and what are the relative (dis)advantages are.