# Saving in command line

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm using Mathematica on a Raspberry Pi and I'm done with calculations at the moment. I'd like to save this but there isn't a way to do it like there is for PC version (File -> Save). How can I save this file?

Answer (score 4):

We can save all current definitions in the `Global` context with this

```
Save[ "tmp.wl", "Global`*"]
```

We can open the "tmp.wl" file like a notebook in the MMA, or get the definitions back in a later command line session like this

```
Get["tmp.wl"]
```

We can use any file name and extension we like.

See the `Save` documentation for saving only specific variables.

Note that this does not save your entire session, but only the current definitions.

Comment: Did you mean `tmp.m`?

Comment: Good catch.  I tested it using `tmp.nb` on a Raspberry Pi and was a little surprised that it worked so I went with it without thinking it through.  Later I realized `tmp.wl`  would be better.  I'm changing my answer to reflect your comment and my preference to use the `.m` extension only for Matlab files.  Thank you.

Comment: I was tempted to cite this [discussion of file name extensions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98981), but decided not to.