# File formats of the Wolfram language

Tags: scripting

I am new user of Wolfram language and Wolfram Mathematica. And want to understand differences and purpose between file formats of ".m", ".wl" and ".wls". I have read about it from the official site but didn't understand and didn't find any detailed information about it in anywhere.
About ".nb" all is clear, it front-end file format of the Mathematica and can use only with it. Also, I understood, that if I am going to use Wolfram Workbench with the Eclipse IDE, I should use - save my codes in ".m" format. But what about ".wl" and ".wls" formats?

Comment: FYI: [What's the difference between *.m and *.wl file format?](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1507777)

Comment: FYI: [What is the difference between a .wl package and a .m package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98981/13)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, thank you for the links. Now, all is clear for me about ".m" and ".wl" formats. About ".wls" format, I have found from the official site [WolframScript (for the Command Line)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/?source=nav)

Comment: @MarcoB, yes, I have read the all answers. I already understood the answer to the question. Thank you very much all of you for quick response. I understood that .m and .wl the same file format, there is not any differences between. .m format is old one, but .wl is new. Also, as I understood, .wls for writing the scripts directly on the command line of the OS.